# How to make a dynamic dependent dropdown list in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new here so if this is not allowed please tell me.

I do not have office 365 and therefore cannot use the Unique or Filter functions.

I have found an alternative finding unique values:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$15, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$7:F7, $B$3:$B$15), 0)),"")
```

- And it works.

I am struggling with filtering unique values that are dependent on the column before it. The examples I see on the internet use the unique and filer combination like this:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B15,A1,A15 =J3)
```

The J3 is part of my dynamic drop down list and refers to the previous column which deternmines what values to show on the aformentioned section I am stuck on.

If this is not clear please tell me.

thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add a sample of data? What do you mean with "filtering unique values that are dependent on the column before it"? Is [this article](https://trumpexcel.com/dynamic-excel-filter/) of any help to you?

Comment: Hello Evil Blue Monkey, What I mean by filtering for unique values is explained much better in the attached article below.                                                                                                                            Also I was using this article as a refrence (attached below). It looks simple to do but I do not have office 365 and cannot use those functions. https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/09/02/create-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-excel/

Comment: Also I have read the article you sent and I have already tried something similar to this

Comment: Ok. Try to post a sample of data, preferably with a image/description of what result you are expecting (like: if select "dessert" on the first dropdown, the second one should have "cake", "ice-cream", "profiterol"). Maybe i can suggest you something.

Answer (score 0):

I created a template with dependent drop down lists.I hope it will be useful for you.

The database includes products, product categories, suppliers of products and prices. Even if the data in the table is mixed, we can comfortably examine the products by grouping them by category and suppliers on linked drop-down lists , the data can be entered to other sheets.

[image]

[**Review this address**](https://eksi30.com/create-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-lists-on-userform/)